# Pointers for Member Functions

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I am currently trying to create a program to calculate the mass of a rocket with given time values by passing an array to a member function of a class. I want to use a pointer for the array. How do I go about doing that. Should the pointer be initialized in int main or the class. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class equip
{
public:
    double mass[999999999], velocity, height, *time[999999999];
    double calcmass(double* time); 
    double calcvelocity();
    double calcheight();
    double calctime();
private:
    double T = 7000;
    double g = 32.2;
    double K = 0.008;
};

double equip::calcmass(double* time)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i=999999999; i++)
    {
        return mass[i] = (3000 - 40 * time[i]) / g;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    equip rocket;
    ifstream infile;
    string filename;
    cout<<"Enter input file name for time values: ";
    cin>>filename;
    infile.open(filename.c_str());

    while(infile.fail())
    {
        cerr<<"Error opening file. \n";
        cout<<"Enter file name: ";
        cin>>filename;
        infile.open(filename.c_str());
    }

    for(i=0; i<999999999; i++)
    {
        infile>>rocket.time[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<999999999; i++)
    {
        cout<<rocket.mass[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Forget C-style arrays exist and never think about or use them again. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` in their place and your life will be much simpler.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include details of how the code you've posted is _not working as intended_. What is the output you are getting, and what do you want?

Comment: And as @JesperJuhl says, those large, stack-allocated arrays (`mass` and `time`) are almost certainly not what you want to do. Use `std::vector` if their size can change, or `std::array` if their size is know at compile-time.

Comment: `double mass[999999999]` !!!!

Comment: and why is `times` pointers?

Comment: There is no way that large of an array will work on a stack variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`equip` is a very large object. About 14 gigabytes in fact.

Automatic variables such as `equip rocket` are allocated on the execution stack. The default size of the execution stack on most desktop systems is about 1 to few megabytes.

A 14 gigabyte object will most definitely overflow a 1 megabyte stack.

Solution: Always use dynamic allocation for large arrays such as used here. Simplest solution is to use `std::vector`. Also, are you certain that you need the arrays to be that big?

---

> ```
> for(i=0; i=999999999; i++)
> ```

This loop looks like it will never end because 999999999 is always true.

> ```
> {
>         return ....
> ```

But in fact, the loop never repeats because the function immediately returns. Neither choice makes sense, although in combination their silliness sort of cancel each other out.

Answer (score 0):

Change the size of array to a practical real number. If can't , go through Dynamic memory allocation.